# Increment date by 1 day based on another column's date from previous record

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, date

I am using **SQL server 2008 R2** and I don´t have LAG and LEAD functions.

I have this inicial table and I need that StartDate is equal to EndDate from previous record plus 1 day.
See Result Table.

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this self join:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime2](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

some data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([id], [date]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([id], [date]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2021-01-03T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([id], [date]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2021-01-06T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([id], [date]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-01-10T00:00:00.0000000' AS     DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([id], [date]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2021-01-20T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] OFF
```

and this query:

```
select t.id,t.date as [from], tnext.date as [to]
from table_1 as t left join
     table_1 as tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id -1
     order by 1
```

[image]

Comment: Works just fine. Thanks!